# How to monitor connection in local network

Tags: microservices, haproxy, monitor

I have a ton of services: Node(s), MySQL(s), Redis(s), Elastic(s)...
I want to monitor how they connect to each other: Connection rate, Number alive connection... (Node1 create 30 connection to Node2/MySQL/Redis per second...) like Haproxy stat image attached below.

[image: Haproxy stat]

**Currently i have two options:**

- Haproxy (proxy): I want to use single service Haproxy to archive this but it's seem very hard to use ALC detect what connection need forward to what service.
- ELK (log center): I need to create log files on each service (Node, MySQL, Redis...) and then show them on the log center. I see that a ton of works to do that without built-in feature like Haproxy stat page.

How to do this? Is log center good in this case?

Comment: I work with such environment and I use ElasticSearch for application logs (Elastic is good for full text search engine) and Prometheus for metrics collection and metric analytics specific for monitoring and alerting. After much soul searching and testing, this is my recommendation.

Comment: Looking at your history of questions, you have accepted none of them. Please refer to [What to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

I think your problem is not collecting and pipelining the statistics to Elasticsearch, but instead the ton of work extracting metrics from your services because most of them do not have metric files/logs.

You'd then need to export them with some custom script, log them and capture it with filebeat, stream to a logstash for text processing and metric extraction so they are indexed in a way you can do some sort of analytics, and then send it to  elasticsearch.

**My take on the answer**

At least for the 3 services you've referenced, there are [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) exporters readily available and you can find them [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/). The exporters are simple processes that will query your services native statistics APIs and expose a prometheus metric API for Prometheus to Scrape (poll).

After you have Prometheus scraping the metrics, you can display them in dashboards via [Grafana](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/) (which is the de facto visualization layer for Prometheus) or bulk export your metrics to wherever you want (Elasticsearch, etc..) for visualization and exploration.

**Conclusion**

The benefits of this approach:

1. Prometheus can auto-discover new nodes you add to your networks
2. Readily available exporters from haproxy, redis and mysql for
   Prometheus
3. No code needed, each exporter requires minimal
   configuration specific to each monitored technology, it can easily
   be containerized and deployed if your environment is container
   oriented, otherwise you just need to run each exporter in the
   correct machines
4. Prometheus is very, very easy to deploy

Answer (score 1):

Use ELK - elasticsearch logstash and kibana stack with filebeat. **Filebeat** -will share the log file content with logstash 
**Logstash**-will scan, filter and share the needed content to elastic search 
**Elasticsearch**- will work as a db, store the content from logstash in json format as documents. 
**Kibana**- with kibana you can search the required info. Also you can plot graphs and other visuals with the relevant data.